# Apache redirect

Tags: apache-2.2, php, redirect, rewrite

I am trying to redirect the URL:

http://www.mydomain.com/productpage.php?id=34

to

http://www.mydomain.com/products

I have tried using:

```
Redirect permanent     /productpage.php?id=34      http://www.mydomain.com/products
Redirect permanent     http://www.mydomain.com/productpage.php?id=34      http://www.mydomain.com/products
```

Could anyone point out what I am doing wrong here?

Cheers

Eef

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you can pass variables via RedirectPermanent. Try an Alias:
`Alias     /productpage.php?id=34      http://www.mydomain.com/products`
If that doesn't work, you can try a computationally expensive RewriteRule:
`RewriteEngine on

 RewriteRule ^productpage\.php\?id=34 http://www.mydomain.com/products`

Answer (score 0):

The one rule should work.

```
RedirectPermanent     /productpage.php?id=34      http://www.mydomain.com/products
```